# How to sort queryset by annotated attr from ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Simplest example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Group(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupMembership')

class GroupMembership(models.Model):
    user = ...
    group = ...
```

I want to get list of Groups ordered by annotated field of members.

I'm using trigram search to filter and annotate User queryset.
To get annotated users I have something like that:

```
User.objects.annotate(...).annotate(similarity=...)
```

And now I'm trying to sort Groups queryset by Users' "similarity":

```
ann_users = User.objects.annotate(...).annotate(similarity=...)
qs = Group.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('members', 
    queryset=ann_users))
qs.annotate(similarity=Max('members__similarity')).order_by('similarity')
```

But it doesn't work, because `prefetch_related` does the ‘joining’ in Python; so I have the error:

```
"FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'members' into field."
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect that you have a database function for similarity of names by trigram search and its Django binding or you create any:

```
from django.db.models import Max, Func, Value, Prefetch

class Similarity(Func):
    function = 'SIMILARITY'
    arity = 2

SEARCHED_NAME = 'searched_name'
ann_users = User.objects.annotate(similarity=Similarity('name', Value(SEARCHED_NAME)))
qs = Group.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('members', queryset=ann_users))
qs = qs.annotate(
    similarity=Max(Similarity('members__name', Value(SEARCHED_NAME)))
).order_by('similarity')
```

---

The main query is compiled to

```sql
SELECT app_group.id, MAX(SIMILARITY(app_user.name, %s)) AS similarity
FROM app_group
LEFT OUTER JOIN app_groupmembership ON (app_group.id = app_groupmembership.group_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN app_user ON (app_groupmembership.user_id = app_user.id)
GROUP BY app_group.id
ORDER BY similarity ASC;
-- params: ['searched_name']
```

It is not exactly what you want in the title, but the result is the same.

Notes: The efficiency how many times will be the SIMILARITY function evaluated depends on the database query optimizer. The query plan by EXPLAIN command will be an interesting your answer, if the original idea by raw query in some simplified case is better.

Comment: Thank fro your answer. I got your idea. Unfortunately, I don't have single function "Similarity"; my search is more complicated - it uses Double Metaphone + Trigrams search by several fields.

Comment: And another thing: I guess that Similarity shouldn't be used twice, doesn't it?

Comment: If you write a similarity expression, I can rewrite it to one function. An annotation can not be reused by related fields (or I can't it). Relations are to models not to queries or querysets. Therefore there is currently no way to reuse an annotation by a related field. It is more important to check if number of Similarity evaluation is len(User) + len(GroupMembership) or 2 * len(User), for your backend. Twice slower ORM than a handwritten SQL is not bad.

Comment: @MarkMishyn The part annotate max similarity is completely independent on prefetch_related. One can work without other. I guess that nobody can write even a raw SQL that evaluates both by one Similarity evaluation. Even a complicated similarity that depends on more fields can be written as one Query expression used twice or as a function.